# How to check if 10 minutes is passed in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

So that is my question. Is it possible to do something like this:
`DateTime.Now > Date.AddMinutes(10)` ?? Problem is that its now add minutes on date ? How can i do that?

I need to check if 10 minutes is passed...

```
var start = new Date();
   if(start.addMinutes(10) > Date.now())
        {
              $scope.isCancelTicketButtonVisible = true;
               $scope.$emit("appIsCancelTicketButtonVisible", $scope.isCancelTicketButtonVisible);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$timeout` service documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout).

Comment: im not sure is that good in my case because i want to show button if 10minutes is passed but user may or may not click on that button.$timeout is just delay ...am i right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach-

```
var firstDate = new Date();
var finalDate = firstDate.setMinutes(firstDate.getMinutes() + 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update

**html**

```
<div ng-bind="elapsed()"></div>
```

**code**

```
var startDate = Date.Now();
function elapsed(){
  if(start.addMinutes(10) > Date.now()){
     console.log('do stuff here');
  }
}
```

---

Use the $timeout service like below. After a 'sleep period' of 10 minutes the code will execute.

```
$timeout(function() {
    console.log('Timeout fired')
    $scope.isCancelTicketButtonVisible = true;
    $scope.$emit("appIsCancelTicketButtonVisible", $scope.isCancelTicketButtonVisible);
}, 600000);
```

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: i dont need to be execute after some period i need to be executed if 10minutes is passed  from time of creation

Comment: Then why not call this code when this 'time of creation' occurs? This is a timer function you call when applicable.

Comment: Problem is that time of creation is in one format and datetime now is in other format...i dont know how to get minutes and compare them if u know what i mean?